# Indirect function with a string variable in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to insert this function in a string variable in my vba: 
`a` is the sheet name - `=INDIRECT((a)&"!f8")`

This code not work  : 
`s = "=INDIRECT((" & "'" & a & "'" & ")&" & "!f8""")"`

Comment: What do you mean by ***does not work***?

Comment: I don't have a correct formula because of the " and ! chars... always I get an error

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: the problem with "!f8" ... how I can convert it to string i have a problem with the !

Comment: Huh? `"!f8"` is a string. And you still haven't disclosed the error message.

Comment: It might be helpful to you to read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Then edit your question to better help us understand your problem, and help you with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all . 
i find the answer :

ActiveCell.Value  = "=INDIRECT(" & """" & "'" &   a   & "'" & "!f8" & """" & ")"

Answer (score 0):

Change "Tabelle3" with the name of the worksheet.

```
Sub FormulateMe()

    Dim s As String
    s = "Tabelle3"
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=INDIRECT(""" & s & "!A1"")"

End Sub
```

Comment: I have a same problem

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Sub FormulaToCell()
Dim a, s As String
a = Sheets(1).Name 'Change to whichever sheet
s = "=Indirect(""" & a & "!F8"")" 'insert the formula as a string
Range("$A$1").Value = s 'insert string into cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain why it doesn't work? What do you want exactly that this code doesn't do? Can you maybe post an expected output?